# Que deberia modificar en este codigo para heredar las variables de la funcion excel a function($sheet)?

Tags: php, laravel, variables, herencia

Necesito enviar las variables a la function($sheet para utilizar esas variables en las consultas sql) que deberia modificar en este codigo para poder utilizarlas? MUCHAS GRACIAS DE ANTE MANO

```
public function excel($inicio,$quer,$que,$query)
{
    Excel::create($query, function($excel){
        $excel->sheet('DISPONIBILIDAD', function($sheet){
            $upset=DB::table('externos')
                        ->select(DB::raw('fecha_iniI, id_cajero, COUNT(id_incidente) AS cantidad, CASE WHEN(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))) IS NULL THEN "EN PROCESO" ELSE concat(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))," Minutos") END AS OFFLINE,CASE WHEN ((100-(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))*100)/525600)) IS NULL THEN "INCIDENTE ABIERTO" ELSE concat((100-(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, concat(fecha_iniI," ",hora_iniI), concat(fecha_fin," ",hora_fin)))*100)/525600)," %") END AS UPS'))
                        ->where([
                        ['fecha_iniI', '>=',$que],
                        ['fecha_iniI', '<=',$quer],
                        ['id_cajero', '=',$query]
                        ])
                        ->groupBy('id_cajero')
                        ->orderBy('UPS','asc')
                        ->get();
            $sheet->row(1,['Fecha Primer Incidente','Codigo Cajero','Numero de Incidentes','TIEMPO OFFLINE EN MINUTOS','UPSET ANUAL',]);
            foreach($upset as $index=>$upset)
            {
            $sheet->row($index+2,[
            $upset->fecha_iniI,
            $upset->id_cajero,
            $upset->cantidad,
            $upset->OFFLINE,
            $upset->UPS,
            ]); 
            }               
        });
    })->export('xls');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Según [la documentación](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/array.html), puedes hacerlo con `use`, por ejemplo:

```
Excel::create($query, function($excel) use($data) {
    $excel->sheet('DISPONIBILIDAD', function($sheet) use($data) {
```

Aquí `$data` sería un array con los datos que quieres pasar.

Comment: Te agradezco demasiado amigo... ya terminé de arreglar todo el sistema gracias a ti... Un abrazo.